# In a multinomial distribution, compute $\mathbb E[I_i \cdot I_j]$ where $I_i = 1$ when event $i$ doesn't occur at all

Tags: probability

Suppose there are $n$ independent trials each of which can take the values :  $n_1,n_2, \cdots, n_r$ with probabilities : $p_1,p_2,\cdots,p_r$.

Let the Indicator variable $I_j = 1 $ when the event $j$ never occurs in the $n$ trials and $0$ otherwise.

I am trying to prove that $\mathbb E[I_i \cdot I_j] = ( 1 - p_i - p_j)^n$ where $i \ne j , 1 <= i <= r , 1 <=j <= r ; ~i,j$ are integers

**Attempt:** From a previous problem, I know that $I_i, I_j$ are not independent.

Now  $\mathbb E[I_i \cdot I_j] = 1 \cdot P(I_i \cdot I_j = 1)$

$P(I_i \cdot I_j = 1) = P(I_i = 1 ~\cap~I_j = 1) = P(I_i = 1 ~\cup~I_j = 1) - P(I_i = 1) - P(I_j = 1)$

> How can I evaluate this further? So, neither $i$th or $j$th event happens with probability $(1 - P(\text{ith event or jth event}))^n$.  What I am a little confused is : As per the intended result, how is $P(\text{ith event or jth event})) = p_i+p_j$. These events are not mutually exclusive!

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$I_i I_j=1$ if $I_i=1$ and $I_j=1$, meaning that neither event $i$ nor event $j$ ever occurs, otherwise it is zero. Therefore

$$E[I_i I_j]=1 \cdot P(\text{neither } i \text{ nor } j \text{ ever occurs}) + 0 \cdot (1-P(\text{neither } i \text{ nor } j \text{ ever occurs})).$$

Can you proceed from there?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I was able to come to this:  $P(I_i \cdot I_j = 1) = P(I_i = 1 ~\cap~I_j = 1) = P(I_i = 1 ~\cup~I_j = 1) - P(I_i = 1) - P(I_j = 1)$ . Am I in the right direction?

Comment: @MathMan Evaluating that probability is easier than that. Keep in mind here that you actually already know the answer, so you can reverse engineer the logic to get that answer if you have to.

Comment: So, neither $i$th or $j$th event happens with probability $(1 - P(\text{ith event or jth event}))^n$.  What I am a little confused is : How come $P(\text{ith event or jth event})) = p_i+p_j$. These events are not mutually exclusive

Comment: Only if they were mutually exclusive could we write the result we want to prove. Am I making a mistake?

Comment: Thank you. I got it